# Access model object from view in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a "person" view that very simplified looks like this:

```
<div>
<span>{{person.firstName}}</span>
<span>{{person.lastName}}</span>
</div>
```

Is there a way in javascript using jQuery to access the `person` object? The object is getting injected from app.js, but I need to manipulate it a little bit in a javascript file specific for the "person" template, but I can't find a way to access it.

This is the relevant part of app.js:

```
app.get('/person', function (req, res) {
    res.render('Pages/person.html', {
        title: "People",
        person: mockData.people
    });
});
```

Comment: Where does the template get generated?  You should be able to modify `person` before it gets thrown into the template.  Show us the relevant parts of app.js

Comment: @Mike Done. And sorry if I'm missing something. I'm new to this stuff :)

Comment: @Mike and one other thing, I just realized it's not a handlebars template. It's just a view getting that jQuery routes to.